# Cannot resolve symbol 'list_items'

Tags: android

I have created the Layout Resource names as list_items, then why the Error ?
inside res folder
Can anyone help me resolve this Issue

Thanks
I dont know it is asking me to add more details
so here are rendom details, but please help resolve the issue

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {


        List<Model> modelList;
        Context context;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Model> modelList, Context context1) {
            super(context, resource);
            this.modelList = modelList;
            this.context = context1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, false);

            TextView textViewName = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView textViewImageUrl = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.description);

            //Getting the hero for the specified position
            Model model = modelList.get(position);

            //setting hero values to textviews
            textViewName.setText(model.getTitle());
            textViewImageUrl.setText(model.getDescription());

            //returning the listitem
            return listViewItem;

        }
    }
```

**list_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache & Restart?

Comment: no did not tried that

Comment: try it once and check

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'list_items' @ViduraPrasangana

Comment: as @amin said, try `File->Invalidate Cache & Restart`

Comment: In which folder is it stored?

Comment: inside res ->layout

Comment: still occured ? Are your sure the problem is on the list_items file location ? When I see the code, it seems that you're using the wrong xml file because there are not title or description components